# Torch: My custom Layer not work on GPU

Tags: deep-learning, torch

I implement a custom softmax layer on torch, it works very fine on CPU mode, but when I change it to GPU mode, it fails to work, the loss of my model remains unchanged after I do some forward and backward iteration, while on CPU mode, it decreases after every epoch.

My custom softmax layer is

```
local MySoftMax, Parent = torch.class('nn.MySoftMax', 'nn.Module')
function MySoftMax:__init()
    Parent.__init(self)
end
--input = batch * 2 * 40 * 40 * 40
--output = batch * 1 * 40 * 40 * 40

function MySoftMax:updateOutput(input)
    tmp_input = input:clone()
    size_input = tmp_input:size()
    self.output = torch.CudaTensor(size_input[1], 1, size_input[3], size_input[4], size_input[5])
    exp_input = tmp_input:exp()
    for i = 1, size_input[1] do
        tmp_output = exp_input[i][1]:clone()
        sum_exp_input = exp_input[i][1]:add(exp_input[i][2])
        self.output[i][1] = tmp_output:cdiv(sum_exp_input)
    end
    return self.output
end

function MySoftMax:updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
    tmp_input = input:clone()
    size_input = input:size()
    self.gradInput = torch.CudaTensor(size_input[1], 2, size_input[3], size_input[4], size_input[5])
    exp_input = tmp_input:exp()
    for i = 1, size_input[1] do
        tmp_exp_input = exp_input[i][1]:clone()
        add_exp = exp_input[i][1]:add(exp_input[i][2])
        pow_exp = add_exp:pow(2)
        mul_exp = tmp_exp_input:cmul(exp_input[i][2])

        self.gradInput[i][1] = mul_exp:cdiv(pow_exp)
        self.gradInput[i][2] = self.gradInput[i][1]
        self.gradInput[i][2] = -self.gradInput[i][1]
        self.gradInput[i][1]:cmul(gradOutput[i][1])
        self.gradInput[i][2]:cmul(gradOutput[i][1])
    end
    return self.gradInput
end
```

and the GPU training code is:

```
model = model:cuda()
criterion = criterion:cuda()
inputs = torch.CudaTensor(batch_size, 1, bbx_size, bbx_size, bbx_size)
targets = torch.CudaTensor(batch_size, 1, bbx_size, bbx_size, bbx_size)
model:training()
torch.manualSeed(train_size)
shuffle = torch.randperm(train_size)
print '==> epoch = '
print(epoch)
epoch_error = 0.0
for t = 1, train_size, batch_size do
    xlua.progress(t, train_size)
    for i = 1, batch_size do 
        inputs[i] = train_input[shuffle[t + i - 1]]
        targets[i] = train_output[shuffle[t + i  - 1]]
    end
    local feval = function(x)
        gradParameters:zero()
        outputs = model:forward(inputs)
        err = criterion:forward(outputs, targets)
        df_do = criterion:backward(outputs, targets)
        model:backward(inputs, df_do)
        epoch_error = epoch_error + err
        return f, gradParameters
    end
    optim.sgd(feval, parameters, config)
end
```

my model is:

```
cnn_state = {8, 16, 32, 64, 128}
pool_size = 2
filter_size = 2
batch_size = 64

model = nn.Sequential()

--stage 1
--1*40*40*40
model:add(nn.VolumetricConvolution(1, cnn_state[1], filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--8*39*39*39
model:add(nn.VolumetricConvolution(cnn_state[1], cnn_state[2], filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--16*38*38*38
maxpool1 = nn.VolumetricMaxPooling(pool_size, pool_size, pool_size, pool_size, pool_size, pool_size)
model:add(maxpool1)
--16*19*19*19

--stage 2
--16*19*19*19
model:add(nn.VolumetricConvolution(cnn_state[2], cnn_state[3], filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--32*18*18*18
model:add(nn.VolumetricConvolution(cnn_state[3], cnn_state[4], filter_size + 1, filter_size + 1, filter_size + 1))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--64*16*16*16
maxpool2 = nn.VolumetricMaxPooling(pool_size, pool_size, pool_size, pool_size, pool_size, pool_size)
model:add(maxpool2)
--64*8*8*8

--stage 3
model:add(nn.VolumetricConvolution(cnn_state[4],cnn_state[5], filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--128*7*7*7
--deconvolution
model:add(nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(cnn_state[5], cnn_state[4], filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--64*8*8*8
model:add(nn.VolumetricMaxUnpooling(maxpool2))
--64*16*16*16
model:add(nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(cnn_state[4], cnn_state[3], filter_size + 1, filter_size + 1, filter_size + 1))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--32*18*18*18
model:add(nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(cnn_state[3], cnn_state[2], filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--16*19*19*19
model:add(nn.VolumetricMaxUnpooling(maxpool1))
--16*38*38*38
model:add(nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(cnn_state[2], cnn_state[1], filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
model:add(nn.ReLU())
--8*39*39*39
model:add(nn.VolumetricFullConvolution(cnn_state[1], 2, filter_size, filter_size, filter_size))
--2*40*40*40
model:add(nn.MySoftMax())
```

My model works fine on CPU mode, it's loss decreases and prediction becomes better and better if I use Tenser instead CudaTensor. however in GPU mode, it doesn't work.
I think the problem may lies in my custom layer implementation, maybe it won't work on GPU. So I wonder is there anything I need to pay attention while implement a layer run on GPU? or is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what happens in your particular case, but generally you should not change the pointer of the state variable such as `gradInput`. It could be the case that backprop somehow depends on that. Try changing this line

```
self.gradInput = torch.CudaTensor(size_input[1], 2, size_input[3], size_input[4], size_input[5])
```

with this line:

```
self.gradInput.copy(torch.CudaTensor(size_input[1], 2, size_input[3], size_input[4], size_input[5]))
```